# SimpleDateFormat returning wrong day

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to convert the date from May 15, 2009 19:24:11 PM MDT to 20090515192411.
But when I tried the below code, the readformat itself is taking the input as May 16 instead of May 15

Here is my code.

```
    String dateInString = "May 15, 2009 19:24:11 PM MDT";

    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = readFormat.parse(dateInString);
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(date); // Prints May 16, 2009 07:24:11 AM MDT

    String formattedDate = "";
    if( date != null ) {
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }

    System.out.println(formattedDate); // Prints 20090516072411
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: 19 and PM looks invalid to me

Comment: Resolved this myself.. modified readFormat from "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z" to "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z" (hh to HH)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `HH` instead of `hh` to read a time in 24-hour format.  Java's "lenient dates" are doing you in here - 19:24pm is being parsed as 8 hours after 11:24pm.

Answer (score 4):

```
String dateInString = "May 15, 2009 19:24:11 PM MDT";
```

is **invalid**, time could be either 24 hour format or it could have AM/PM